# How to run dart server on background?

Tags: dart

how to run my dart server forever when terminal is closed? Is there any package like pm2

I use for node js:

```
pm2 start index.js
```

Comment: `nohup <your command> &` might be what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the some in dart, what you need is the to run your dart program entry point let saya  `pm2 start main.dart` you can add other pm2 arguments options as per https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

Answer (score 0):

This work for me
update the list of available packages and their versions from the repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

install curl:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

install pm2:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -g pm2
```

install run dart server:

```
pm2 start dart --name kt_eclaim_server -- run project_folder/bin/my_server.dart
```

You can check the logs of your PM2 process by running:

```
pm2 logs
```

Hope it helps.